# java. read a file,sort it by some column and print

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a text file

```
category1 1 10 101 good1 1
category6 2 11 105 good5 10
category1 5 13 103 good4 6
category3 6 14 102 good2 5
category5 3 12 107 good1 3
category7 4 12 128 good8 1
category3 5 17 134 good5 8
category2 1 19 143 good4 8
category4 2 16 152 good7 8
category5 9 13 163 good8 6
category9 8 14 165 good4 4
category0 5 15 156 good3 12
category2 6 13 147 good7 1
category7 4 12 138 good5 3
category7 3 12 124 good6 9
category8 8 11 102 good9 6
```

and i need to sort it by category names. This is what I already have:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Data.txt"));
    Map<String, String> map=new TreeMap<String, String>();
    String line="";
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
        map.put(getField(line),line);
    }
    reader.close();
    for(String val : map.values()){
        System.out.println(val);
   }
```

It sorts the file data but shows only unique rows, and I need all to be shown. How to do it ?

Comment: Do you have only unique lines?

Comment: obviously you need to append to some collection other than tree, and use `Collections.sort(a list, probably)`.

Comment: This is surely a command line job eg awk or sort.

Answer (score 2):

Read in your data into a custom class. Declare hash() and equals() for your class. Optional toString() to print output similiar to input. Read lines into objects of custom class (optional with a Scanner), add objects to a List and use Collections.sort() with a custom Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have unique lines, you can use TreeSet - it will take care of sorting for you (alphabetic order should be fine for you).

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Data.txt"));
Set<String> set=new TreeSet<String>();
String line="";
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
    set.add(line);
}
reader.close();
System.out.println(set)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using an implementation of `Map`.  A map will only store one instance a value for a given key.  Without seeing your implementation of `getField()` method, your lines with the same key are getting overwritten when you call `map.put(getField(line),line);`.  I would use a some form of `List` instead of a `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read each line and split(" ") which will give you an array of Strings with the data from that line, then you can check the first index to see what is the category. Using the Hashmap as you did, you could use this first String as the key and add the line to an ArrayList that could be the value for your Hashmap, then you will have all the lines of a given category added to the ArrayList.

Cheers